# Ignore webpack-cli v4 from dependabot updates and keep v3.x

Tags: javascript, yaml, yarnpkg, dependabot

Due to private packages, I am still using Dependabot v1. Below is my javascript (yarn) config.

```yaml
version: 1
update_configs:
  - package_manager: 'javascript'
    directory: '/'
    update_schedule: 'daily'
    version_requirement_updates: increase_versions
    ignored_updates:
      - match:
          dependency_name: 'webpack-cli'
          version_requirement: '^3.3.12'
```

#### What I want?

I want to exclude/ignore webpack-cli 4.x. Whenever dependabot runs, webpack-cli updated to `4.x`. It is incompatible with my app so i need  at most `v3.3.12`. So, I told dependabot to ignore after `^3.3.12` but it still bumps and updates `webpack-cli` to `v4.x`

How can I make sure webpack-cli always stay at `v3`-series?

#### Expected

Dependabot ignore v4

#### Actual

It bumps my `package.json` and `yarn.lock` to **v4**.

Comment: Don't you want to *ignore* `>=4` rather than `^3.3.12`, then?

Comment: Oh! I thought giving `^3.3.12` will ignore after that. So, you mean if I exclude/ignore v4 i need to put that version there? Then I misread the documentation :(. Also does npm/yarn support `>=`?

Comment: Well it will ignore versions above 3.3.12 but explicitly **not** including 4. That's what `^3.3.12` *means*.

Comment: Got it. So **major** version need to be provided in this section.

Comment: You need to provide whatever you want to ignore. Use e.g. https://semver.npmjs.com/ to try out different values and see what matches.

Comment: Awesome tool here! Thanks! I will use it. (P.S.: You may write as an answer so i can accept)